# Capistrano: cap aborted! SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing on host

Tags: capistrano3

I'm trying to deploy code with Capistrano 3 to Ubuntu server from GIT repository, but I'm getting this error.

==========================================================================
    Here is my Gemfile.

```
gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.1.0'

#//Use unicorn as the app server
gem 'unicorn'

#// Use Capistrano for deployment
group :development do
gem 'capistrano-rails'
gem 'capistrano-bundler'
gem 'capistrano-rbenv', "~> 2.0"
end

source 'https://rubygems.org'
```

==========================================================================
    #deploy.rb

```
lock '3.1.0'

#// Define the name of the application
set :application, 'my_app'

#// Define where can Capistrano access the source repository
#// set :repo_url, 'https://github.com/[user name]/[application name].git'
set :scm, :git
set :repo_url, 'git@github.com:jaipratik/rw.git'

set :use_sudo, true

set :log_level, :debug

#// Define where to put your application code
set :deploy_to, "/var/www/my_app"

set :pty, true

set :format, :pretty
```

==========================================================================
    #// production.rb

```
role :app, %w{ubuntu@{IP/Host}}

server '{IP/Host}', user: 'ubuntu', roles: %w{web app}

set :ssh_options, {
keys: %w(/Users/jay/.ssh/id_rsa),
forward_agent: false,
user: 'user'
# auth_methods: %w(password)
}
```

==========================================================================
result for     $ bundle exec cap production deploy --trace

```
** Invoke production (first_time)
** Execute production
** Invoke load:defaults (first_time)
** Execute load:defaults
** Invoke deploy (first_time)
** Execute deploy
** Invoke deploy:starting (first_time)
** Execute deploy:starting
** Invoke deploy:check (first_time)
** Execute deploy:check
** Invoke git:check (first_time)
** Invoke git:wrapper (first_time)
** Execute git:wrapper
INFO[f8299d4f] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp/my_app/ on {IP/Host}
DEBUG[f8299d4f] Command: /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp/my_app/
INFO[f8299d4f] Finished in 0.723 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUGUploading /tmp/my_app/git-ssh.sh 0.0%
INFOUploading /tmp/my_app/git-ssh.sh 100.0%
INFO[b509dfb7] Running /usr/bin/env chmod +x /tmp/my_app/git-ssh.sh on {IP/Host}
DEBUG[b509dfb7] Command: /usr/bin/env chmod +x /tmp/my_app/git-ssh.sh
INFO[b509dfb7] Finished in 0.084 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
** Execute git:check
DEBUG[9646aea0] Running /usr/bin/env git ls-remote git@github.com:jaipratik/rw.git on {IP/Host}
DEBUG[9646aea0] Command: ( GIT_ASKPASS=/bin/echo GIT_SSH=/tmp/my_app/git-ssh.sh /usr/bin/env git ls-remote git@github.com:jaipratik/rw.git )
DEBUG[9646aea0] c452c845bb80f72d3023557d2ea8f776950c659f
DEBUG[9646aea0]
DEBUG[9646aea0] HEAD
DEBUG[9646aea0]
DEBUG[9646aea0] c452c845bb80f72d3023557d2ea8f776950c659f
DEBUG[9646aea0]
DEBUG[9646aea0] refs/heads/master
DEBUG[9646aea0]
DEBUG[9646aea0] Finished in 0.940 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
** Invoke deploy:check:directories (first_time)
** Execute deploy:check:directories
INFO[fa4b1f56] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -pv /var/www/my_app/shared /var/www/my_app/releases on {IP/Host}
DEBUG[fa4b1f56] Command: /usr/bin/env mkdir -pv /var/www/my_app/shared /var/www/my_app/releases
INFO[fa4b1f56] Finished in 0.086 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
** Invoke deploy:check:linked_dirs (first_time)
** Execute deploy:check:linked_dirs
** Invoke deploy:check:make_linked_dirs (first_time)
** Execute deploy:check:make_linked_dirs
** Invoke deploy:check:linked_files (first_time)
** Execute deploy:check:linked_files
** Invoke deploy:started (first_time)
** Execute deploy:started
** Invoke deploy:updating (first_time)
** Invoke deploy:new_release_path (first_time)
** Execute deploy:new_release_path
** Execute deploy:updating
** Invoke git:create_release (first_time)
** Invoke git:update (first_time)
** Invoke git:clone (first_time)
** Invoke git:wrapper
** Execute git:clone
DEBUG[fa77f295] Running /usr/bin/env [ -f /var/www/my_app/repo/HEAD ] on {IP/Host}
DEBUG[fa77f295] Command: [ -f /var/www/my_app/repo/HEAD ]
DEBUG[fa77f295] Finished in 0.081 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
DEBUG[0cc407cc] Running /usr/bin/env if test ! -d /var/www/my_app; then echo "Directory does not exist '/var/www/my_app'" 1>&2; false; fi on {IP/Host}
DEBUG[0cc407cc] Command: if test ! -d /var/www/my_app; then echo "Directory does not exist '/var/www/my_app'" 1>&2; false; fi
DEBUG[0cc407cc] Finished in 0.075 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO[de52ca0e] Running /usr/bin/env git clone --mirror git@github.com:jaipratik/rw.git /var/www/my_app/repo on {IP/Host}`enter code here`
DEBUG[de52ca0e] Command: cd /var/www/my_app && ( GIT_ASKPASS=/bin/echo GIT_SSH=/tmp/my_app/git-ssh.sh /usr/bin/env git clone --mirror git@github.com:jaipratik/rw.git /var/www/my_app/repo )
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing on host {IP/Host}: git exit status: 1
git stdout: Nothing written
git stderr: Nothing written
/Users/jay/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/
```

Comment: This gets resolved if i change the target folder to                     ##  set :deploy_to, "/home/ubuntu/tempsite"  .  Still want to know why it doesnt work on original location ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Capistrano wasn't able to create the folder on ec2. Once I created the folder it worked like a charm.

So if you also have similar issues try creating the folder on ec2 and then execute the cap production deploy.

Comment: Hi JP, where should we create the folder?

Comment: wherever you like, but just be sure that the permission for that location are good, so that when you make a call on that folder, it works fine.

Answer (score 19):

Just write the command in console:

```
 ssh-add
```

If that don't work, write below command in console:

```
 ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

and then re-run the command (i.e. `cap production deploy`), It will work for sure.

Comment: I like your confidence with "It will work for sure"

Answer (score 3):

If all the above solutions did not work for you, try this. It works for me. Cheer.

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/your_private_id_rsa
and run
eval `ssh-agent`
```

---

Ref: http://mjacobus.github.io/2015/08/20/solving-weird-capistrano-problems-with-ssh-authentication.html

Answer (score 2):

So what are the permissions for `/var/www/my_app` in your remote machine ? Make sure they are owned by the same user that you specified in this config option:

```
set :user, "mydeployuser"
```

If not I believe Capistrano defaults to the user you are using to run the 'cap' command on the client machine. Make sure that it has permissions to modify/create `/var/www/my_app`

Since you have:

```
set :use_sudo, true
```

it's possible that sudo may not be setup as passwordless sudo like suggested in the Cap 3 [docs](http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/authentication-and-authorisation/)

Comment: how can i make it use sudo if its not permitted in that location ?

Comment: I think you may not have passwordless sudo setup and cap is defaulting to the login user.

Comment: i think you're right Im using ec2 and i never had to put password for sudo, so whats the solution ?

Comment: Check the "Authorisation" section here: http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/authentication-and-authorisation/

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue when trying to deploy a Rails application to a server using Capistrano.

When I run the command `cap deploy`, I get the error:

```
SSHKit::runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as deploy
```

**Here's how I fixed it**:

The issue was that the server to which I was trying to deploy to did not have my SSH key authorized. I had to do the following:

Generate a new SSH key on my local machine:

```
ssh-keygen
```

Display the contents of the public file. In my case mine was `id_rsa.pub`:

```
cat ~/.ssh/your-public-file
```

Login to the server which you want to deploy the app to:

```
ssh your-username@server-ip-address
```

Paste the contents of the public file into the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file on a new line.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Turns out I forgot to add my Gitlab instance SSH key (the 'runner') to my server's ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file.

Comment: How to get the Gitlab instance SSH key ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting up a new Ubuntu server, public key authentication may be switched off by default which you will have to switch on. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72399679/capistrano-authentication-failed-for-user-ubuntuxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-netsshauth)