# Capistrano: Authentication failed for user ubuntu@xx.xxx.xxx.xxx (Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I can connect via `ssh ubuntu@xx.xxx.xxx.xxx`. but not via `cap production deploy:check`

current

```
set :user, "ubuntu"
set :ssh_options, { forward_agent: true }

server "xx.xxx.xxx.xxx",
       user: fetch(:user),
       roles: %w[web app db]
```

tried

```
set :user, "ubuntu"
set :ssh_options, {
  forward_agent: true,
  user: fetch(:user),
  keys: %w(~/.ssh/id_rsa)
}

server "xx.xxx.xxx.xxx",
       user: fetch(:user),
       roles: %w[web app db]
```

The "current" used to be my setup for other projects, and I just have to `ssh-add` then `cap production deploy`

What changed? or is my config incorrect?

Answer (score 16):

issue:  Authentication failed for user ubuntu@xx.xxx.xxx.xxx (Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed) via capistrano but can ssh directly

debugging:

- `sudo tail -f  /var/log/auth.log` on the server
- then tried `cap production deploy:check` on my local
- `userauth_pubkey: key type ssh-rsa not in PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms [preauth]` appeared from `auth.log`

solution:

- edited then `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

  - find `PubkeyAuthentication` then uncomment(remove `#`)
  - add `PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=+ssh-rsa`
- restart sshd `sudo systemctl restart sshd`

Comment: Excellent, thank you! (P.S.: you can accept your own answers)

Answer (score 1):

`ssh-rsa` has been [disabled by default](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-8.2) for security reasons and should be avoided.

You may need to update the `net-ssh` gem, as support for rsa-sha2-512 and rsa-sha2-256 host key algorithms were [added](https://github.com/net-ssh/net-ssh/pull/771) in version [6.2.0.beta1](https://github.com/net-ssh/net-ssh/blob/2b47176756eaf3bd0d694d87e3a2929e39de105b/CHANGES.txt#L37C3-L37C3).

Updating `net-ssh` directly may not work due to other dependencies, so you may have to update `sshkit`.

```
bundle update sshkit
```

Answer (score 0):

If none of the solutions above works, confirm the location of your ssh using "pwd" on your terminal then insert it here:

```
set :ssh_options, {
  forward_agent: false,
  keys: "/your-directory-based-on-pwd/.ssh/key.pem"
}
```